# Font-style/font-weight for fallback-fonts only?

Tags: css, webfonts

I have purchased some fonts from myfonts.com. Due to a bug, they don't work in IE10. I'm gonna use some fallback fonts.

With webfonts, most people use default values for font-weight and font-styles and import different fonts instead. This is a problem now that I want to use fallback default fonts. I want to do somehting like this:

```
font-family: AvenirLT-BookOblique, Helvetica, Arial;
```

But setting helvtica and arial to font-style: italic. The default font is already italic.
I could make a custom css-file just for IE10, however, that's a bit of a hazzle. Are there any other options? IE10 is the only browser that needs to support this.

Comment: using browser feature detection is a reliable way to target IE10.

Comment: Consider submitting a bug report to the font vendor if the font does not work on IE 10, instead of creating new problems with browser sniffing.

Comment: Done it already, however, the site goes live and I need to have a solutione in the meantime :)

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8q8C2/)

You can achieve desired results in IE10 with jQuery([only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)) or IE conditional Stylesheets for IE<9.

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 10) {
  $('element').addClass('ie10');
}

.ie10{
    //some css here
}
```

or target all versions of IE

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Note:
`$.browser.msie` is deprecated in jQuery 1.9.1